# Can I turn off paper styling on paper elements (globally) in Polymer?

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

I want to use the Bootstrap theme with `paper` elements in a Polymer project.

Can I still use the `paper` elements but turn off their (Material Design) styling globally?

Comment: No you can't just turn them off, but you should be able to fully control their look via css or even create your own bootstrap elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's *paper-friendly* to do that: you should see *paper* as a bootstrap-like implementation of material design in polymer.
Why don't you simply use **custom native** elements with polymer and style them as you wish (bootstraporwhatever) ?

Comment: It's convenient to use the `paper elements` built-in properties and methods without having to recreate them. I am assuming here that when you wrote "**custom native elements**" you meant "**custom elements**." Is that correct? Or is there actually a third category of elements (besides custom elements and native elements)  that I could leverage?

Comment: what i mean by **custom native element** is that you have to do your own polymer element (or web component, not necessarly in polymer) and using only native tags (div, span, h1, etc..) with the _bootstrap-classes_ you want and put extra style in _style_ tag: in fact, you use bootstrap as you usually do, but this time inside an element.